# angular 2 - press command enter to submit a form

Tags: angular

I got a reactive form like so

```
@Component({
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
    <textarea name="detail" id="detail" formControlName="detail"></textarea>
    <div *ngIf="formGroup.controls['detail'].dirty && formGroup.controls['detail'].invalid">This is required</div>
    <button type="submit">Post</button>
  </form>
  `
})
export class CreateDiscussionComponent {

  formGroup: FormGroup;
  submitted: boolean = false;
  constructor() {
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      detail: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2) ]),
      type : new FormControl('discussion'),
    });
  }
  onSubmit(): void {
    this.submitted = true;
  }
}
```

what to do so that I can submit the form by press cmd+enter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
<form (keydown.meta.Enter)="handleFormSubmit($event)">
</form>
```

You can filter your keyboard event by required key combination

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
onKey(ev:KeyboardEvent) {
  // do something meaningful with it
  // check ev.key == command + enter
  console.log(`The user just pressed ${ev.key}!`);
  // call submit form
  if (ev.ctrlKey && ev.keyCode == 13) { // cmd+enter
    this.onSubmit();
  }
}
```